# Use WCF service as source / destination for SSIS

Tags: wcf, ssis, etl

I need to create a SSIS package and I would like to know if I can use a WCF service as data source for it.

The WCF will basically expose domain service for a Entity Framework data source, so through I can access data which does not have OleDB provider, to access directly in SSIS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something in the past, but is more like a hack.

1. Define a variable (say webServiceResultHolder)
2. Bring a "Script task" into the control flow canvas. From the script task call the web service, serialize it and dump the result into the variable defined above.
3. Bring a data flow task, connect the output of the Script Task (step 2) to it.
4. Now go to the "Data flow" tab and bring an "Xml Source". Change its data access mode to "XML data from variable", assign the variable defined and accumulated above to it, set its other properties accordingly (column,etc).

That's a bit ugly, but was the only thing I could think of.